# Several versions into one jar file

Tags: maven, jar, maven-3, pom.xml

I fond something strange which maybe it's caused by wrong configuration.

I have a JavaFX application packaged as jar file. When I manually browse the content of the jar file I found that there are several versions of one file:

[image]

I suppose that these files are previous versions of one file. Is this normal or I'm missing something into the POM configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are anonymous internal classes, because your original java file contains constructions like
new ClassX() {
};